# Typeorm one to one relation with connecting table

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I have the following architecture for my database:

***ManagementServer***

- mgmtID: UUID (Auto Generated, Primary Key)
- *some management server fields...*

***DeviceData***

- deviceDataID: UUID (Auto Generated, Primary Key)
- *some device data more fields...*

***ManagementData***

- mgmtID: UUID (Primary Key, Foreign Key from ManagementServer, One to One)
- deviceDataID: UUID (Foreign Key from DeviceData, One to One)

How can I exactly perform this with typeorm V0.3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this.

```
@PrimaryColumn('uuid')
mgmtId: string

@OneToOne(() => ManagementServer, (managementServer) => managementServer.data)
@JoinColumn({ name: "mgmtId" })
managementServer: ManagementServer;

@Column({ type: 'uuid' })
deviceDataId: string;

@OneToOne(() => DeviceData, (deviceData) => deviceData.data)
@JoinColumn({ name: "deviceDataId" })
deviceData: DeviceData;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**